# How to write a java method that moves an element in a list at the i-th position to the end of the list

Tags: java, list, data-structures, linked-list

i want to Write a method moveToEnd, user of the ADT List. The method takes a list
l and an index i. It moves the element at the i-th position to the end of the
list. 
assuming i to be within the list, and that the first element has
the position 0. and without using any auxiliary data structures. The method
signature is:

```
public static<T>void moveToEnd(List <T>l, int i).
```

**Example 1.1.**

If `l: a → c → d → b → r → x`, then after calling `moveToEnd(l,2)`, l will be: `a → c → b → r → x → d`.

Comment: "Example 1.1"? Instead of copying your homework (almost) verbatim, perhaps it would be nice to show us what you tried?

Comment: You ought to try to do your homework on your own. Anyway, you could try something like : remove the i element from the list, append it to the list, voilà.

Comment: maybe try to use https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html and its functions